# How do I accept the closed parenthesis in Atom Text Editor?

Tags: python, autocomplete, atom-editor, parentheses

This seems like it should be so simple but I'm new to programming and Atom TE.  For Python, when I type "print(" atom will automatically add a ")" so when I continue with "some text" and the closed parenthesis is in front of my cursor, [how do I "accept" the closed parentheses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAG64.jpg) and move on to the next line? [Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ZZq.jpg) moves the closed parenthesis to the next line, [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeWKz.jpg) adds 3 spaces.  What's the point of auto filling the closed parenthesis if I can't accept it and continue on?? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you reach the paren, then type a paren, you will skip over the paren, as if it was never auto-inserted for you. So, if you are in this situation:

```
print("foo bar")
               ^-- cursor is here, BEFORE the paren
```

And you then type `)`, you will end up with:

```
print("foo bar") <-- now the cursor is AFTER the paren
```

You can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line below the current one without moving the paren. It is equivalent to pressing <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of the line, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line and move to it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess the closure is just added as a reminder that it needs to be included.  I was able to find a package someone wrote called "tab-through" that allows me to press tab so advance past it. It looks like Ctrl-Enter will jump down a line when passing one character ie ) but not for two ie ").  Anywho, thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Expand on Dan Lowe's answer.

On Mac you can use <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> to skip past the auto-complete characters and go to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few years old, but it was the first thing that popped up when I tried searching for this same thing.  Also new so correct me if I'm wrong, but I found that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> creates a line break while preserving the ") at the end of the function.  I'm sure they made an update which is why it didn't work before.